# How to apply styles to export to pdf for crystal reports in htmltext

Tags: html, css, pdf, crystal-reports

Here what I want to do.

On the web page, user edits a text area with html markup. Only limited, working html tags for the pdf are used.

Then the user will take the text, and make a crystal report out of it (content details and footer sections).

Then the crystal report will be exported into pdf and downloaded.

Currently, the format is off and I wanted to apply some css styles in order to fake a few line breaks with margin/padding calls.

It's not able to access my css file which is being loaded in this page. I'm not able to set embedded styles to my report as it doesnt work. Maybe i'm not doing it right.

Has any one been able to format crystal reports with HTML Text?